# Making list of list oneliner -python

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
l=[(1,2),(1,6),(3,4),(3,6),(1,4),(4,3)]
```

I want to return a list that contains lists by the first number in each tuple.
Something like this:

```
[[2,4,6],[4,6],[3]]
```

To make a program that iterates on list and writing a whole function that does it is easy.
I want to find a oneliner - python way of doing it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I understand how your input relates to your output, could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> L = [(1,2), (1,6), (3,4), (3,6), (1,4), (4,3)]
>>> [[y for x, y in v] for k, v in groupby(sorted(L), itemgetter(0))]
[[2, 4, 6], [4, 6], [3]]
```

**Explanation**

This works by using [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). `groupby` finds **consecutive** groups in an iterable, returning an iterator through key, group pairs.

The argument given to `groupby` is a key function, `itemgetter(0)` which is called for each tuple, returning the first item as the key to `groupby`.

`groupby` groups elements in their **original order** so if you want to group by the first number in the list, it must first be sorted so `groupby` can go through the first numbers in ascending order and actually group them.

```
>>> sorted(L)
[(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 6), (3, 4), (3, 6), (4, 3)]
```

There is the sorted list where you can clearly see the groups that will be created if you look back to the final output. Now you can use `groupby` to show the key, group pairs.

```
[(1, <itertools._grouper object at 0x02BB7ED0>), (3, <itertools._grouper object at 0x02BB7CF0>), (4, <itertools._grouper object at 0x02BB7E30>)]
```

Here are the sorted items grouped by the first number. `groupby` returns the group for each key as an iterator, this is great and very efficient but for this example we will just convert it to a `list` to make sure it's working properly.

```
>>> [(k, list(v)) for k,v in groupby(sorted(L), itemgetter(0))]
[(1, [(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 6)]), (3, [(3, 4), (3, 6)]), (4, [(4, 3)])]
```

That is almost the right thing but the required output shows only the 2nd number in the groups in each list. So the following achieves the desired result.

```
[[y for x, y in v] for k, v in groupby(sorted(L), itemgetter(0))]
```

Comment: +1 for great comprehension.. how did you get that from the original question!

Comment: @Levon Thanks, I just did a question kinda like this but i'm not sure why it is hard to understand...

Comment: @Levon just the way it goes when you know about [groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#list-comprehensions)

Comment: @Boud I still don't understand how the input and output relate, never mind `groupby` :) .. I can lookup groupby of course (not the other)

Comment: @jamylak I think you are up to decompose the one-liner and to explain the intermediate results step by step...

Comment: @Boud Wrote a quick description :D

Comment: @jgomo3 Yeah `itemgetter` is more readable for things like this. Also usually `_` is a placeholder for unused variables so I'm not sure if you really wanna use it like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [(1, 2), (1, 6), (3, 4), (3, 6), (1, 4), (4, 3)]

d = {}
for (k, v) in l:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

print d.values()
```

I know it's not a one liner, but perhaps it's easier to read than a one liner.

Comment: +1 This is probably the best way to do it if the question didn't ask for a one liner. I would suggest changing `(k, v)` to `k, v`

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could do that. Thanks.